# How do I synthesize salicylic acid?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I'm looking to synthesize salicylic acid in my school laboratory for an investigatory project. The Kolbe's reaction looks promising:

[image]

Any suggestions on where to get the $\ce{CO2}$ from?
Will the reaction of vinegar + $\ce{NaHCO3}$ be okay? Does this reaction need a suitable temperature and/or catalysts? I tried to search for similar experiments but the others usually use reagents and catalysts inaccessible to me.

Comment: Do you have access to solid CO2 (dry ice)?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the reaction is performed at CO2  pressure 100 atm. It may not be a suitable scenario for safety reasons.

Comment: Reimer-Tiemann followed by oxidation may be more achievable in a school lab  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reimer%E2%80%93Tiemann_reaction  see procedure  http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV3P0463

Comment: @Waylander No, I don't.

Comment: @AdityaKumarPanda  then look at the R-T procedure which is done with hydroxide and chloroform as IMO you will struggle to get a high enough concentration of CO2 in your reaction mixture.

Comment: @Waylander would it be possible to do a riemer tiemann reaction with carbon tetrachloride instead of chloroform? (to skip the oxidation step)

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati  no - the mechanism requires deprotonation of chloroform by hydroxide as the first step, carbon tetrachloride will not do this. Also Carbon Tetrachloride is a serious carcinogen

Comment: @Waylander What is the 'riemer-tiemann carboxylation' being referred to here by the OP?https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86765/reimer-tiemann-like-reaction-of-catechol-with-diiodomethane

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati  see my answer below

Comment: I would suggest a different starting material: aspirin. The hydrolysis is possible under mild conditions, and the reagents are less dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Riemer and Tiemann originally reported that using carbon tetrachloride in place of chloroform gives salicylic acid as major product plus p-hydroxybenzoic acid. It is mentioned in this review by Wynberg [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr60204a003) and this Indian Journal of Chemistry paper [here](https://irgu.unigoa.ac.in/drs/bitstream/handle/unigoa/347/Indian_J_Chem_30B_1991_800-801.pdf) which has experimental conditions. This seems to have received little attention (which is why I was initially unaware of it), possibly because yields appear low. Other researchers report that the *para* product predominates  (see the Indian Journal of Chem paper). The catalytic effect of copper metal in giving the *para* isomer was reported [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01161a530)

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve phenol in a solution of sodium hydroxide (NaOH) and water. Pass carbon dioxide (CO2) gas through the solution while keeping it cool in an ice bath. This forms sodium salicylate. Acidify the solution with dilute sulfuric acid (H2SO4) to precipitate salicylic acid. Filter and wash the resulting salicylic acid crystals. Purify the product by recrystallization if necessary.

Comment: This will work PROVIDED you have a good source of CO2 - either compressed gas or dry ice. The OP does not.

Comment: Does this work well at normal pressures?